# How to pass value to a specific thread based on the thread's ID

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

So I'm running server on one thread and I'm running clients on the other threads. Each client is connected to a different socket and the server is connected to a different socket than that of the clients. Each client thread is stored in a list, and the respective socket the client corresponds to would be the thread's ID. So when a message comes into the server I want to send the message to specific client thread based on the ID of the thread. So how can I achieve this? Is there some sort direct way I can communicate between specific threads?

Comment: May be bind the sockets to different ports in the server and clients, and send the message to the specific port of the client

Comment: Use queues http://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html

Comment: could you show me an example to putting a message in the queue for a specific thread?